# Executing python script in node application

Tags: javascript, python, html

I am very new to javascript / nodejs / web app development. I have a python script which would perform data crawling and storing the crawled data into the database when executed. The script would require users to input a date which would crawl data created on the particular date that is being submitted.

I have a node application which have a button to submit the date, where ideally would executed the python script when clicked. Can anyone advise me on how I can do this? Or are there any good tutorials I can follow for this?

Answer (score 1):

[python-shell](https://github.com/extrabacon/python-shell) sounds like exactly what you need. Here's one of their examples:

```
var PythonShell = require('python-shell');

PythonShell.run('my_script.py', function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('finished');
});
```

It's very easy to use. They also have examples on communicating inbetween Python and Node.js.

Comment: hi, how to dynamically print the output from the python script? @Ivan

Comment: hi, because I would like to add a progress bar to monitor the progress of the execution of my python script

Comment: Hey, sorry for a delayed response. The Github page I linked in my answer has information on exchanging data inbetween Python and Node.